# How can you open a URI from the command line?

Tags: terminal, termux, automate

I recently started playing with the app called 'Automate'. The starting block for each Automate flow provides a URI. Can this URI be used to initiate a flow? Can I accomplish this from the command line? Specifically, I would like to call Automate flows from within a Termux environment.
I assume this can be done with `am start ...` but I haven't had any luck trying different commands (and I have successfully used `am` from within Termux before, so I don't think that's an issue). I have very limited knowledge of Android intents.

I tried running `am start -d content://rest-of-uri` and I received a prompt asking which app to open, I chose Automate and the notification appeared for a second but the flow didn't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/automate-user/IPmrJ4HjXwk), you can use these commands:

```
am start -a com.llamalab.automate.intent.action.START_FLOW -d content://com.llamalab.automate.provider/flows/13/statements/1
```

or

```
am start -a com.llamalab.automate.intent.action.START_FLOW -d content://com.llamalab.automate.provider/flows/13/statements/1 -n com.llamalab.automate/.StartServiceReceiver
```

Replace `content://com.llamalab.automate.provider/flows/13/statements/1` with your flow URI.

The first command worked for me while the second was giving an error in Termux and `result=0` in Terminal Emulator.

Comment: Thanks! The first one is working great. Is there a way to pass data to the flow as a variable?

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible as I see no input variable for the Flow beginning block. What I have read is that you can write your variable to a file, then read it from your Flow.

Comment: Oh yeah that should work, thanks!